# Multiplying only naturally adjacent integers in a list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10]
```

I want to multiply only adjacent numbers whose difference is 1 to get a final list.

The process in this example would be:

```
[1*2*3*4, 6*7, 9*10]
[24, 42, 90]
```

Comment: What happened when you tried to do it?

Comment: Have you tried to write a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to an array then split after taking the `np.diff` then use `np.prod`:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10]
a = np.array(l)
outlist = [*map(np.prod,np.split(a,np.where(np.diff(a)!=1)[0]+1))]
```

---

```
print(outlist)
#[24, 42, 90]
```

Comment: Ahh! The split is the trick I wasn't picking up on.